# Hystrix Dashboard: How to use

Tags: hystrix

I have a local web service using Jersey and the path looks something like

```
http://localhost:5000/search?...
```

Then I installed the Hystrix dashboard to my Tomcat following this tutorial https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix/wiki/Dashboard

What URL do I use in the highlighted text box? I have tried localhost:5000/hystrix.stream, but it didn't work (my local service was running).

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that I didn't register the servlet.

I use dropwizard so just added the following code and it worked.

environment.getApplicationContext().addServlet("com.netflix.hystrix.contrib.metrics.eventstream.HystrixMetricsStreamServlet", "/hystrix.stream");